# Can you create a List of Objects in C# the same way you would in Javascript?

Tags: c#, list, object, razor-pages

In Javascript I know you can create an array of objects as so:

```js
var myColumnDefs = [
    {key:"label", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
    {key:"notes", sortable:true,resizeable:true},......
```

Is it possible to do something similar in C#?

I tried creating a property in a class as so:

```cs
public List<Object> Projects { get; set; }
```

And in Razor Pages I tried to create some objects:

```cs
public void OnGet()
{
    Projects = new List<Object> {
        {title = "thing"},
        {...},
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think you probably want a Dictionary and not a List, if you want to reference items by name

Comment: new { foo = "bar" }

Comment: `var myColumnDefs = new List<object> { new {key = "label", sortable = true, resizeable = true}, new {key = "notes", sortable = true, resizeable = true} };`

Comment: Or yeah, a dictionary.  But you will still need to new up items to fill it.  Also, the array initialization syntax depends on having ( I believe) an Add method present on the collection object.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

Comment: C# is not Javascript, a list of objects is not a very useful thing by itself, and is usually a sign of a suspect design (unless there is compelling architectural reasons to do so). In C# we tend to create classes to form a strongly typed paradigm to help keep design succinct, neat and structured, additionally to keep code fluent maintainable and predictable. You should look into structs and classes, interfaces, and strongly typed collections, You will find your time in C# a lot more rewarding, and your code a lot more expressive and maintainable

Answer (score 1):

Like this …

```
        Projects = new List<Object>(new[] {
            new { title = "thing1" },
            new { title = "thing2" }
        });
```

And also to add …

```
        Projects.Add(new { title = "thing" });
```

… or …

```
        Projects.AddRange(new[] {
            new { title = "thing1" },
            new { title = "thing2" }
        });
```

Comment: Excellent.  Now they just have to figure out how to use anonymous objects.

Comment: Yeah... different question :)

Answer (score -1):

As you may suspect from the comments you are getting; trying to make one programming language look like another usually causes problems. You should try to follow the conventions of the language you are writing the program in.

For example, C# is designed to be strongly-typed. That means you usually define rules for what your data contains, and how your program is allowed to behave. One of the ways you do this is by defining classes; which are like a template or rules for a collection of data. For example:

```
class Project
{
    public string Title { get; }

    public Project(string title)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(title));

        Title = title;
    }
}
```

Defines a new type of data called a Project, which must contain a single nonempty string called a Title. Anyone can read the Title of a Project, but only the Project itself can change the Title. This is usually what you want. Classes are just rules, you actually create an instance of a class with the `new` keyword:

```
var myFirstProject = new Project("Project one");
```

You can create a list of projects with syntax like:

```
var projects = new List<Project>
{
    new Project("thing1"),
    new Project("thing2")
};
```

Do not think this is a waste; the rules you define are actually useful to you; it allows the IDE to fill in a lot of code using Intellisense or Autocomplete. It prevents you from making mistakes, like assigning to something you never expected to be assigned to. It can also improve performance by allowing the compiler to make optimizations based on things it knows can't happen.

Use the features of whatever language you program in, do not try to circumvent them.